# iAd development - more errors than successful test ads

Tags: ios, iad

> While you are developing your application, iAd Network sends test
>   advertisements to your application. To assist you in validating your
>   implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test
>   your error handling code. You can also test your error handling
>   support manually by turning your device’s wireless capability off.

Ok, it says the above in the developers guide, but in reality its failing more often than serving the test page, for 2 days now! I get a the test ad page once every 10 minutes it seems !!!  Little disproportionate for testing.....

Is this how it's going to be in live? I don't want to be deploying my paid ap for free if it's not even going to send any ads!

Anyone got any experience of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By experience it is very variable in test environment, I've seen days as you describe and days with a good flow of ads. Now ... live it is very different, the "fill rate" as they call it (% of requests answered with and ad) is pretty low, maybe 2% on iPad and 5-10% on iPhone. Besides, iAd serves ads only in certain countries, ie. mostly in US and a bit in the UK, France, Italy, Spain, ... And by experience it serves more ads to the iPhone than iPad. My app on iPad received virtually nothing outside the US from iAd.

Now on the positive side, the remuneration of ads is the best for iAd when you have the chance to receive ads. I ended up implementing a fallback network (AdMob) when iad doesn't receive anything. I did that myself but read there is something called AdWhirl that seems to provide help on that.

Comment: Good advice - I think I'm going to do that too and fallback on AdMob. What about landscape mode? I'm following the rules... my host view has bounds of 0,0,1024,768 and presentInView always returns NO in test environment.... how have you found that?

Comment: I'm observing many errors when testing also. Most of these are "Application has iAd Network configuration error". I've been tracking some statistics on this testing "fill rate" and I'm observing about 50% errors. Seems odd in a testing environment for iOS6 when you have Settings tools for setting the fill rate. However, I observe something similar with Apple's iAdSuite ContainerBanner code, so it seems it not just my code.