# why iAds not working in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I am using iOS SDK 4.2

My application is not universal application(iPhone/iPad) but it can be downloaded in iPad and works fine in both devices.

Now I have integrated iAd in my application.I've followed [iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) example. Its working fine in iPhone. But iAds not working when I download in iPad !!!

I found **The BasicBanner** and **ContainerBanner** examples in iAdSuite are configured to support both iPhone and iPad as it creates universal build.

I want to know that is it necessary to create universal app for iAd ???

Thanks....

Comment: @Emil: there is no error ... iAd is not appeared in iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my post here

[iAd development - more errors than successful test ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042986/iad-development-more-errors-than-successful-test-ads)

Put breakpoints on the ad delegates and see if they are returning failures or success. You should get at least some response.

In debug mode apple will often send failures to simulate the iAd network being down.

In production, there is a very low fill rate for iAds - so there might not be an ad available.!

My app is iPad only, and i got ads. So no, it doesn't have to be universal.

Comment: in iPhone its working fine..Also I am using Enterprise certificate so it displays test advertise.Its fine as its not live yet